# How to dynamically update custom links between sandbox and production?

Tags: deployment, sandbox

I have a custom link in my sandbox: `http://cs7.salesforce.com/00Q/e?name_salut....`

However, when deploying to the production, the link is still pointing to the sandbox, while the production is at `eu1` [instance]

- off course I can make the change manually - but I will probably forget one day
- Is there a way to build the link that will take account the instance it uses?

Comment: Can the link be made relative instead of absolute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a best practice, you should make your links relative, you can exclude the domain "http://cs7.salesforce.com" and just use "/yourcomponent".

Not following this rule is not just an issue when deploying between different environments but also if Salesforce decides to migrate your org to another instance.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the converted URL, for example how would https://na5.salesforce.com/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed look? I've tried deleting various parts of the beginning of the URL, for a custom link but in each case, the link isn't recognized.

Answer (score 4):

This document (Building Salesforce Custom Links) might help you out:

[Salesforce Web Integration](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_web_integration_links.pdf)

Comment: Never knew there was so much help information available for this... nice one.

Comment: Document appears to be removed. That is why it is much appreciated to add more information in an answer than an offsite reference.

Comment: @Samuel, I found and updated the link and added some context to my original comment.

Answer (score -1):

What I found to work was to use the system field:

```
{!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}
```

at the beginning of the URL.

So the URL looks like this: `{!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}/00Q/e?name_salut....`

Comment: Does this work for non-Sites URLS, too?